Next.js app router configuration permanent redirect
I have to do permanentRedirect in next.js app configuration so as to get HTTP status as 308/302 i.e permanent redirect. But it is showing 307 only i.e temporary redirect in the network tab.
There are two ways of using it-

In next.config.mjs,
In the app/[folder]/page.tsx.
In both it is showing 307 only.
I am not using it in next.config.mjs because I have to tweak the suffix of slug a little bit like-
localhost:3000/how-to-grow/best-way-to-grow-mango to localhost:3000/how-to-grow/grow-mango in the redirection. i.e keep the middle part of url same(how-to-grow) but change the last part of url slug i.e(how-to-grow-mango to grow-mango). And this is not possible from my side in next.config.mjs redirect as I didnot find any online document for this step, but it is quite doable in app/[folder]/page.tsx through string manipulations. And I tried the same which is giving me 307 instead of 308 as http status code.

I tried the code as -
But it is giving 307 as http status code.
I am sharing the screenshots of http status code, ad code snippets[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/0kVdAKQC.png)
import {permanentRedirect} from "next/navigation";

export default async function Page({ params }: PageProps) {
  const { locale, slug } = params;
  if(slug.includes("best-way-to-grow")){
    const usableSlug = slug.split("-");
    permanentRedirect(`/how-to-grow/grow-${usableSlug[usableSlug.length-1]}`);
  }
   

  return (
    <div>
      <div>hello</div>
    </div>
  );
}

Please help me with the right code fix and solution,
also, in the next.cofig.mjs file, please suggest me what modification can I do to make the suffix different from the source url in the destination url, only if the redirection will show 307 as http status code. Her is the code of next.config.mjs file-
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    async redirects() {
        return [
          {
            source: '/:locale/how-to-grow/best-way-to-grow-:suffix*', // Source path pattern to match URLs like /how-to-buy/best-way-to-buy-ethereum
            destination: '/:locale/how-to-grow/grow-:suffix*', // Destination path to redirect to URLs like /how-to-grow/grow-mango
            permanent: true, // Sets the status code to 307
          },
        ];
    },
};

export default nextConfig;

